# Why does mathematica not recognize the equality of these two terms?

Tags: functions, numerics, expression-manipulation, numerical-value

I have two expressions which I have analytically verified to be equivalent but when I check them numerically via mathematica I don't obtain numerical agreement.

They are

```
 1/eps + (2 - xb Log[1 - 1/(1 - xb)] - Log[1 - 1/xb]) + 1/12 (48 + 2*\[Pi]^2 - 24 xb Log[1 - 1/(1 - xb)] + 
6 xb Log[1 - 1/(1 - xb)]^2 - 24 Log[1 - 1/xb] + 
12 xb Log[1 - 1/(1 - xb)] Log[1 - 1/xb] + 6 Log[1 - 1/xb]^2 - 
12 PolyLog[2, 1/(1 - xb)] + 12 xb PolyLog[2, 1/(1 - xb)])*eps
```

and

```
2 + 1/eps + 4 eps + (eps Pi^2)/6 + (1 + 2 eps) (-1 + xb) Log[(-1 + xb)/xb] - 1/2 eps (-1 + xb) Log[(-1 + xb)/xb]^2 + eps (-1 + xb) PolyLog[2, 1/(1 - xb)]
```

Writing $$x_b \ln \left(1-\frac{1}{x_b} \right) = -x_b \ln \left(1-\frac{1}{1-x_b}\right)$$ for example I can check analytically that the expressions coincide. But for any $x_b \in (0,1)$, the range of values taken by the parameter $x_b$, I don't get numeric agreement.

I thought maybe mathematica is assuming a particular branch for the logarithms for prescribing numeric values but  then probably this choice of branch is universal across both numerical checks so most likely this isn't the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's really a question about the underlying math involving the standard logarithm branch cut choice.

Answer (score 2):

For the simpler problem, you can see that

```
{x Log[1 - 1/x], -x Log[1 - 1/(1 - x)]} /. x -> 0.2
{0.277259 + 0.628319 I, 0.277259 - 0.628319 I}
```

so the answers have the same real part, but conjugate complex parts. One way to check numerically would be to check agreement between the magnitudes.

Comment: I see, in my attempt at showing these expressions were equal, I used the fact that ln(x) =-ln(1/x). Is that only true if x is positive?

Comment: @CAF - Yes, evaluate `Simplify[Log[x] == -Log[1/x], x > 0]` and `Simplify[Log[x] == -Log[1/x], x < 0]`

Comment: Thanks! So it means to make the correct conversion of log(-x) to log(x) (where x is positive) I need to use the correct branch of log to get the sign of I*Pi correct and then I can use this replacement. Do you know how one knows how to get the branch correct? Is this usually provided by some external information?

Comment: What is the goal? If you want this to check an answer numerically, then why not just use the real part, or take the magnitude, or check that the answers are complex conjugates.

Comment: I wanted to compare the two expressions in the OP and show they are equal. From the comments in the other answer, they are equal in interval xb [-1,1] only if log(-xb)=log(xb)-ipi, which coincides with branch of the log. I could probably check the magnitude of these expressions if I put the `Abs` in the correct places? +1

Answer (score 2):

```
f1[xb_, eps_] = 
  1/eps + (2 - xb Log[1 - 1/(1 - xb)] - Log[1 - 1/xb]) + 
   1/12 (48 + 2*π^2 - 24 xb Log[1 - 1/(1 - xb)] + 
      6 xb Log[1 - 1/(1 - xb)]^2 - 24 Log[1 - 1/xb] + 
      12 xb Log[1 - 1/(1 - xb)] Log[1 - 1/xb] + 6 Log[1 - 1/xb]^2 - 
      12 PolyLog[2, 1/(1 - xb)] + 12 xb PolyLog[2, 1/(1 - xb)])*eps;

f2[xb_, eps_] = 
  2 + 1/eps + 
   4 eps + (eps Pi^2)/6 + (1 + 2 eps) (-1 + xb) Log[(-1 + xb)/xb] - 
   1/2 eps (-1 + xb) Log[(-1 + xb)/xb]^2 + 
   eps (-1 + xb) PolyLog[2, 1/(1 - xb)];
```

For these two expressions to be equal

```
f1[xb, eps] == f2[xb, eps] // FullSimplify[#, 0 < xb < 1] &

(* I + eps (2 I + π) == 0 *)
```

If the two expressions were unconditionally equal then `f1[xb, eps] == f2[xb, eps] // FullSimplify[#, 0 < xb < 1] &` would evaluate to `True`. However, since it simplifies to an equation then this equation represents the required condition for equality of the two expressions. Verifying equality when the condition is met:

```
f1[xb, -I/(2 I + Pi)] == f2[xb, -I/(2 I + Pi)] // 
 FullSimplify[#, 0 < xb < 1] &

(* True *)
```

For a specific numeric value for `xb`

```
f1[xb, -I/(2 I + Pi)] == f2[xb, -I/(2 I + Pi)] /. xb -> 0.7

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer too, but could you add some comments to tell me what you have done?

Comment: So the conclusion is that the two expressions are only equal when eps = I/(2*I+Pi)?

Comment: @CAF - Yes, provided also that `0 < xb < 1`

Comment: Thanks! Just a small side comment: if I extend the interval of `xb` to `-1<xb<1`, then the `fi` are equal provided `log(-xb)=log(xb)-I*Pi`. This happens to coincide with a branch of the logarithm used to deal with negative log arguments. Do you know if mathematica by default takes the rule `log(-z)=log(z)+I*Pi` in its evaluation of logs with negative arguments?

Comment: @CAF - `f1[xb, eps] == f2[xb, eps] // FullSimplify[#, -1 < xb < 1] &` evaluates to `xb*((-I)*Pi - Log[-xb] + Log[xb])*
     (2 + 4*eps - I*eps*Pi - eps*Log[-xb] + 
        eps*Log[xb]) == 0`. I do not understand how you concluded that there condition is `log(-xb)=log(xb)-I*Pi`

Comment: Oh I just put the first bracket to zero because I wanted a condition without involving epsilon (or that xb=0 identically)

Comment: @CAF - `Log[-xb] == Log[xb] - I*Pi // Simplify[#, xb < 0] &` evaluates to `True`

Comment: Yes, so that would mean that log(-z) = log(z) + i*pi would evaluate to true for z >0, so mathematica default branch involves the + pi sign I think.